# 'python path/to/script params' throws error "..\depot_tools\win_tools-2_7_6_bin\python\bin\python.exe: can't open file 'path/to/script'"

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, cmd, v8

I am trying to follow [these](https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-build-v8-on-windows-and-not-go-mad-6347c69aacd4) steps to run Hellow World code in v8.  I getting below error while running the command python path/to/script params in cmd:

> ..\depot_tools\win_tools-2_7_6_bin\python\bin\python.exe: can't open
>   file 'path/to/script': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have the below installed in my machine:
VS 2017,
VS 2015

I have also set the environment variables as

> ```
> DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0 
> GYP_MSVS_VERSION =2015
> ```

Am I missing anything here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the location of the Script you are trying to execute. 
I don't think that "path/to/script" is an actual location.